# how to achieve contact page with font awesome icons like my image using flex box in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-awesome

[image]

how can I achieve this layout regarding image,

I have developed code

this is my CSS file I got the exact output. but I faced an issue if my address changes big text means my icon get collapsed cant align center, how can I changed that.this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffmwm2br/5/). I don't want to go with bootstrap.need to get some knowledge with flex property

```css
 *{
      margin: 0;
    }
    section{
      background-color: #555;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .contact{
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .contact h2{
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .contact li{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .contact li:last-child{
      margin: 0;
    }
    .contact a{
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .contact a:hover{
      color: yellow;
    }
    .contact p{
      color: white;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    .contact .fa{
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      line-height: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
 <section>
      <div class="contact">
        <h2>Contact us</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
          <a href="#">questions@newco.com</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 
          <a href="#">111-222-333</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
          <p>NewCo, Inc <br>
            123 Main St. <br>
            Somewhere, CA 12345
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      
    </section>
```

Comment: For the people that don't have access to imgur, could you please create a snippet to show what you currently have, and explain what you would want to have please ?

Comment: what is the issue, the image is the same as the code your provided

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: hi change the address to some long text ,the icon place are changes,i need those icons are fixed position and text only need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `h2` doesn't have an *icon* on its left, it needs to be compensated for that, along with that the `ul` has a default `padding`.

By adding a new rule, `.contact ul`, with `padding-left: 0`, add `margin-left: 40px;` (the sum of *icon's* width/right margin) to the `.contact h2` rule and remove `text-align: center`, you will be able to achieve what you want.

Stack snippet

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
section{
  background-color: #555;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.contact{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.contact h2{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  /*text-align: center;                   removed  */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;                  /*  added  */
}
.contact ul{
  padding-left: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
.contact li{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.contact li:last-child{
  margin: 0;
}
.contact a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.contact a:hover{
  color: yellow;
}
.contact p{
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.contact .fa{
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="contact">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <a href="#">questions@newco.com</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        <a href="#">111-222-333</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
        <p>NewCo, Inc <br> 123 Main St. 123 Main St.123 Main St. <br> Somewhere, CA 12345
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</section>

</body>

</html>
```